# Send email on update table in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to send an email when a column update occurs. I have read, that do this directly in update trigger is a bad practice, so another way is to create job, wich will check column on update and send emails for updated records.

Please tell me, this approach is correct or exist more accurate solutions?

Comment: when you want to send email? Means are you okay to send email once in a day by capturing all the changes?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, once an hour by capturing all the changes is ok

Answer (score 0):

Update Trigger is bad practice only when it is impacting the same table.In your scenario update trigger in best way.

Refer :[Guideline to create triggers](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/331025/Be-Very-Careful-When-You-Write-Sql-Trigger)